# Convert currency symbol to currency code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to redirect urls to a new domain and manually edit any currency symbol to a currency code that I set in htaccess.

So

```
https://example.com/ticket12/$4.44
```

should redirect to

```
https://mynewexample.com/ticket12/USD4.44
```

Then when a different option comes `../vipticket17/USD6.45` those values pass too to the new site. So the wildcard value of the ticket should be forwarded along with the ticket name value which is another variable.

Here is what I have so far, just need to figure out how to pass the ticketname variable to the new url. Perhaps the tricky part here being the $ symbol which is used by regex/htaccess as a wildcard as well

```
RewriteRule ^ticket12\/\$\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mynewexample\.com\/ticket12\/USD$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This kind of URL seems weird.
I think you should use GET /ticket12 to get the ticket
and POST /ticket12 with post payload {currency: 'USD', amount: '4.00'}

then you can validate the values and payload within your server app and do the redirect using php/node etc.

Comment: Rainer - Just needs 2 variables, surely this is something regex can handle easily? Justin - The ticket name will also perhaps change so need to pass anything between those forward slashes

Comment: Will this part **contain** the word `ticket` everytime?

Comment: Hi Justin, No the value and currency of the ticket varies, along with the ticket name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion, I guess it's safe to assume that you have no other urls like `/xxx/$yyy` (where `xxx` can be several -sub-folders) concerned by this same context.

So you can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/\$([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$ https://mynewexample.com/$1/USD$2.$3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the following generic  rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)/[$]([0-9.]+)$ http://newsite.com/$1/USD$2 [L,R]
```

Comment: This looks good, but when I try and add the extra currencies I need ```RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)/[$]([0-9.]+)$ http://newsite.com/$1/USD$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/[£]([0-9.]+)$ http://newsite.com/$1/GBP$2 [L,R]``` The new entry doesn't work, I need to add a handleful of other currencies such as euro etc

Comment: @Gracie `£` doesn't work inside regex character class `[]` . You can simply remove the square braces. Try this pattern `^(.+)/£([0-9.]+)$`